# Ext JS 4 - Unchangeable cookies

Tags: javascript, extjs, cookies, extjs4, session-cookies

I need to prevent hijack attacks through HTML cookies. I'm using [Ext.state.CookieProvider](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.state.CookieProvider) to manage sessions; but I want it to be unchangeable by end users (actually hijackers). It'll be changeable through only application functions. Are there any solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will eventually be solved with ECMAScript 6's [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) functionality, which is supported in the newer versions of Firefox and Chrome (if you enable experimental JavaScript):

```
const cookie = "username=David;";
cookie = "username=Lincoln;";
console.log(cookie);  // returns "username=David;"
```

But other than waiting for that, if your cookie is an Object, you can use [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), which is pretty nifty:

```
var cookie = {cookie: 'username=David;'};
Object.freeze(cookie);
cookie.cookie = 'username=Lincoln;';  // returns "username=Lincoln;"
console.log(cookie.cookie);  // returns "username=David;"
```

Unfortunately, the cookie object can be overwritten, but it at least protects against simple attacks.

Comment: What I have done is only letting cookies to be changed for **1 time**. I've implemented it through its value; it should be `null(undefined)` in order to set new value.

Answer (score 0):

As cookies are a feature of the client, there is always a way to tamper with it. You must use them in conjunction with sessions on the server side. That way your able to detect when the cookie was tampered with.

This is not related to extjs, but applies generally to cookies.

Comment: thanks @LorenzMeyer for your care. You're absolutely right, if the topic is security, there is no guaranteed way. And of course server side is real place of cookie management; but as we all do we occasionally store some information at cookies. At least I don't want it to be changed by a simple command like `setCookie('x', 'y')`.